# Creating value pairs from some vectors

Tags: julia

Suppose we have a set of pair like the following, and each pair comes with a value attached to it. For isntance the value of pair `(1,2)` is `2.5`.
There are another set `p1` which represent a set of persons. Each person connected to set of pairs. For instance, for `p in p1` their associated pairs are the first elemenst of  `p1_pairs` (i.e. `[(1, 2), (1, 7), (2, 3)]`.

```
Pairs  = [(1, 2), (1, 7), (2, 3), (2, 5),(3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 5), (5, 2)]
Values = [ 2.5,    4.1,    7.4,    5.6,   2.8,    3.7,    6.9,     0.2,    3.2 ]

P1 = ['p','q']
p1_pairs = [   [(1, 2), (1, 7), (2, 3)], 
               [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5) ,(5, 2)] 
           ]
```

The question is, how to bulid up a parameter `person_values` such that it return the value of the associated pairs?

For instance `person_values['p',(1, 2)] = 2.5` and `person_values['q',(2, 3)] = 7.4`.
In other words `person_values` will be indexed over elemets of `p1` and `p1_pairs` and then assign s the corresponding values to them based on their `values`

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your question you want this:

```
julia> pv = Dict( Pairs .=> Values);

julia> [getindex.(Ref(pv), vals) for vals in p1_pairs]
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [2.5, 4.1, 7.4]
 [2.5, 7.4, 5.6, 3.2]
```

Comment: Hello @Przemyslaw Szufel thanks. actually the question is how to have such a parameter like `person_values[ {elements of p1} , { elemnts of pairs} ] =  related values`. For example `person_values['q',(5,2)] = 3.2`

Comment: You could have a `Dict` where the key is a tuple - try:  `Dict(('q',(5,2)) => 3.2)`